# Does diversity theory ever consider personality or other social groupings?

Tags: diversity

Has anyone critiqued modern diversity theory in that it arbitrarily selects some categories over others? For example, why shouldn’t a diversity ranking take personality into account?

Comment: This site is for questions about the mechanics of academia, from student to retirement. It's not about discussion of topics of research in academia, which would make the site far too broad for common interest.